# Is it possible for AWS Lambda to run a Windows binary via Wine?

Tags: aws-lambda, wine

I have a Python script with a Windows `.exe` dependency, which in return relies on a (closed-source) Windows DLL. The Python script runs just fine in Ubuntu via a call to Wine.

Is it possible (and practical) to run this on AWS Lambda?

What would be involved in preparing the code package?

Comment: I've got Python Lambdas that have a native library dependency and it works pretty well.  Ultimately I package the shared library with in the ZIP and within that zip file, in the "lib" directory, I can put shared libraries.  Now that is not a full executable, just .so libraries.  You'd have to load Wine as a shared library (no, I'm not sure how) and have it run the .exe.  Honestly, you might be better off with a small EC2 running Windows - this sounds like a pain.

Comment: This process would be intermittently run, but would still need to run on demand with minimal delay. Lambda seems like the perfect spot for it (other than this closed dependency issue obviously), since otherwise I'd be paying per hour for a machine which may not take any requests for hours at a time.

Comment: Totally agree but, for Lambda at least, you've got a pretty challenging setup.  The Windows dependency really makes things difficult.  Depending on the load a t2.nano is less than USD $5/month.

Comment: So do you imagine that if I wanted to get this working I'd need to compile Wine binaries for Amazon Linux, and package these along with the script and the exe/DLL? Does Lambda have package size limits...?

Comment: To answer my second question there, the uncompressed total package size has to be under 250M, and compressed (zip) it has to be under 50M ([source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-list)).

Comment: Unless I'm not grabbing all the necessary files (definitely possible), Wine on my (Ubuntu) machine including its documentation etc takes up 125M uncompressed and 27M zipped, so the limits should be OK...

Comment: @tremby, did you get this to work in the end?

Comment: @ikkjo Afraid I can't tell you. I handed it off in the end to another developer.

Comment: @tremby, I understand. Many thanks for getting back!

Answer (score 7):

Update: the [lambda container image feature supports images up to 10gb](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/). I haven't tried it but I think that would be a viable approach, and wouldn't require the hacks I did below to reduce the wine build size.

TL;DR;

Is it Possible? Yes.

Is it practical? The approach I tried **is not**. A better approach might be to try and put wine into different lambda layers or a custom execution environment.

Will it work for you? It depends, deployment package size and disk space are the limiting factors.

---

Old, somewhat hacky method to fit wine into the regular lambda environment:

I compiled a custom wine with minimal dependencies for lambda, compressed it and then put it onto S3.

Then, in the lambda at runtime, I downloaded the archive, extracted it to `/tmp` and ran it with a custom empty wine prefix.

My test windows executable was 64bit [curl.exe](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.66.0_2/curl-7.66.0_2-win64-mingw.zip).

#### 1. Compile Wine for Lambda

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html, I first tried `amzn-ami-hvm-2018.03.0.20181129-x86_64-gp2`, but it had an older compilation environment and wouldn't configure.

With AMI `amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20190313-x86_64-gp2` on a `t3.2xlarge` ec2, I was able to configure and compile. These are the commands I used, references [aws-compile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html) and [building-wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine):

```
> sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
> mkdir -p ~/wine-dirs/wine-source
> git clone git://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git ~/wine-dirs/wine-source
> cd ~/wine-dirs/wine-source
> ./configure --enable-win64 --without-x --without-freetype --prefix /opt/wine
> make -j8
> sudo mkdir -p /opt/wine
> sudo chown ec2-user.ec2-user /opt/wine/
> make install
> cd /opt/
> tar zcvf ~/wine-64.tar.gz wine/
```

This was only a 64-bit build. It also had almost no other optional wine dependencies.

#### 2. Reduce the size of the Wine build further

I removed a lot of optional dependencies from the wine build at compilation time, but it was still too big. `/tmp` is [limited to 500MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

I deleted files in the package subdirectories, including what looked like optional libs, until I got it down to around 300MB uncompressed.

I verified that wine would still run `curl.exe` after deleting files from the build.

#### 3. Compress it

I created a `tar.bz2` of wine and curl with default bz2 options, it ended up around 80MB. The compressed and extracted files together required about 390MB.

That way there is enough room to both download the archive and extract it to `/tmp` inside the lambda.

```
> du -h .
290M    ./wine/lib64/wine
292M    ./wine/lib64
276K    ./wine/share/wine
8.0K    ./wine/share/applications
288K    ./wine/share
5.0M    ./wine/curl-7.66.0-win64-mingw/bin
5.0M    ./wine/curl-7.66.0-win64-mingw
12M     ./wine/bin
308M    ./wine
390M    .

> ls
wine wine.tar.bz2
```

#### 4. Upload `wine.tar.bz2` to S3

Create an S3 bucket and upload the `wine.tar.bz2` file to it.

#### 5. Create the Lambda

Create an AWS Lambda using the python 3.7 runtime. While this uses a different underlying AMI than what wine was built on above, it still worked.

In the lambda execution role, grant access to the S3 bucket.

RAM: `1024MB`. I chose this because lambda CPU [power scales with the memory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html).

Timeout: `1 min`

#### 6. Lambda code:

I needed to follow the advice from this [question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188146/use-wine-without-user-interaction) to change the wine prefix inside the lambda. I also turned off the display as it suggested.

e.g.:

```
handler():
  ... download from S3 to /tmp, cd to /tmp

  subprocess.call(["tar", "-jxvf", "./wine.tar.bz2"])
  
  os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ''
  os.environ['WINEARCH'] = 'win64'
  os.environ['WINEPREFIX'] = '/tmp/wineprefix'
  
  subprocess.call(["./wine/bin/wine64", "./wine/curl-7.66.0-win64-mingw/bin/curl.exe", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"])
```

[image: successful execution of wine in lambda]

**Success!**

Comment: poida, thanks heaps for your description here, a bit of a lifesaver! I was wondering if you could clarify a couple of things for me? How do you remove optional dependencies at compilation time? And by package subdirectories do you mean the files in /opt/wine/lib64/wine? Cheers

Comment: @ElecEnthusiast at the `> ./configure --enable-win64 --without-x --without-freetype --prefix /opt/wine` step. `Without x` and `without freetype` were enough for the proof of concept.

Comment: By deleting subdirectories and optional libraries, my process was a bit hit and miss, I'd delete one, see if the binary still ran, then repeat. I looked for libraries that I thought wouldn't be needed. In my favour was that curl didn't need many dependencies to run. The more complex program you're trying to run, the harder this will be.

Comment: Can you share the exact lambda code you used for this solution.

Comment: Hi @poida! Thank you so much for sharing these steps. I am looking into something similar. Could you clarify why the compiled package needs to be stored on S3 and can we not package it in a lambda layer?

Comment: hi @ShwetaJ you're welcome! I'm pretty sure you could try putting it into a lambda layer and not in S3, but I haven't tried it. Looks like atm the total lambda container size limit is 10GB, including layers, so that should be plenty of space to install wine

Comment: @poida I followed your steps for compiling wine, zipped the package, and tried to include that in a lambda layer (not in a docker container), and it did throw an error for the package size. Cannot exceed 250MB uncompressed. But deploying as container image would probably work. I am unable to get wine running though with those steps. I posted a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77267403/running-a-windows-exe-with-wine-on-amazon-linux Would be great if you could help with that.